# how to get asl_log to appear in the iOS system console output?

Tags: iphone, ios, logging

I'm investigating whether I can get better performance from asl_log than NSLog on iPhone/iOS (probably...) but I'm stuck at a point where it doesn't seem that asl's log output will show up in the System Console (as viewable by a number of apps like System Console, iConsole, etc).  I know that I'm setting it up right since I open with ASL_OPT_STDERR, and I see the log entries in XCode when the device is tethered.

I've explored lots of interesting stuff online (e.g. http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2008-01-20/asl-logging, https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack) and the best hope seemed to be asl_open() with Facility of "com.apple.console" but alas, the output still doesn't show up in  Console.  Is NSLog the only option?

Answer (score 10):

Add STDERR to ASL and then it shows up in the console

```
asl_add_log_file(NULL, STDERR_FILENO);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set read privileges on the message, using either ReadUID or ReadGID. Setting either to -1 will allow any user/group to view the message according to the header file documentation.

```
aslmsg msg = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_MSG);
asl_set(msg, ASL_KEY_READ_UID, "-1");
asl_log(NULL, msg, ASL_LEVEL_NOTICE, "Hello, world!");
asl_free(msg);
```